# Dovecot/Postfix: Cannot retrieve email from server due to connection timing out

Tags: ssl, email, postfix, dovecot

I am running Dovecot and Postfix on a CentOS 8 server, with Nginx and LetsEncrypt for SSL/TLS.  I'm using the [virtual user](https://wiki.dovecot.org/VirtualUsers) and [domains](https://www.tecmint.com/configure-postfix-and-dovecot-with-virtual-domain-users-in-linux/) configuration.  OpenDKIM, OpenDMARC, ClamAV and SpamAssassin are also in play, as are Roundcube and PostfixAdmin for webmail/admin resp.

Problem: cannot **retrieve** OR **send** messages on Thunderbird.  Attempting to download new messages results in 1-2 minutes of "Connected to pop.domain.com..." before getting alert "Connection timed out to server pop.domain.com".  Thunderbird is configured to work on either imap.domain.com on port 993, or pop.domain.com on port 995.  I have one test account on each, and neither one is working.

Interestingly, can **view** inbox and **receive** emails fine with Roundcube, but **cannot send** without getting "SMTP Error: [451] 4.7.1 Service unavailable - try again later".

Possible culprit(s):

- Misconfigured config variable in Dovecot

  - Possibly stemming from version disparities: my CentOS 7 used **2.10.1** for Postfix, **2.2.36** for Dovecot.
    Whereas current setup uses **3.3.1** for Postifx, **2.3.8** for Dovecot.
- SSL certificate problems?
- Thunderbird config problems?

`dovecot -n`

```
auth_debug = yes
auth_mechanisms = plain login
auth_verbose = yes
default_login_user = vmail
first_valid_gid = 2000
first_valid_uid = 2000
listen = *
log_timestamp = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S "
mail_access_groups = vmail
mail_debug = yes
mail_location = maildir:/var/www/mail/vmail/%d/%n
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
  separator = /
  type = private
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf
  driver = sql
}
protocols = imap lmtp pop3
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0600
    user = postfix
  }
  user = root
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imaps {
    port = 993
  }
  process_min_avail = 1
  user = vmail
}
service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0600
    user = postfix
  }
}
service pop3-login {
  inet_listener pop3s {
    port = 995
  }
  process_min_avail = 1
  user = vmail
}
ssl = required
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/private/fullchain.pem
ssl_dh = # hidden, use -P to show it
ssl_key = # hidden, use -P to show it
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = yes
userdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf
  driver = static
}
verbose_ssl = yes
```

`postconf -n`

```
alias_database                      = $alias_maps
alias_maps                          = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
biff                                = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients            = yes
command_directory                   = /usr/sbin
compatibility_level                 = 2
daemon_directory                    = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory                      = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level                    = 2
debugger_command                    = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd
                                      $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
html_directory                      = no
inet_interfaces                     = all
inet_protocols                      = ipv4
mail_owner                          = postfix
mailq_path                          = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory                   = /usr/share/man
meta_directory                      = /etc/postfix
milter_default_action               = accept
milter_protocol                     = 2
mydestination                       = localhost
myorigin                            = localhost
newaliases_path                     = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
non_smtpd_milters                   = unix:/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.socket, 
                                      unix:/var/run/opendmarc/opendmarc.socket, 
                                      unix:/var/run/spamass-milter/spamass-milter.socket
queue_directory                     = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory                    = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
relay_domains                       = *
sample_directory                    = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
sendmail_path                       = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group                        = postdrop
shlib_directory                     = no
smtp_tls_loglevel                   = 2
smtp_tls_security_level             = may
smtp_use_tls                        = yes
smtpd_client_restrictions           = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_milters                       = unix:/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.socket, 
                                      unix:/var/run/opendmarc/opendmarc.socket, 
                                      unix:/var/run/spamass-milter/spamass-milter.socket
smtpd_recipient_restrictions        = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_relay_restrictions            = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable              = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain             = $mydomain
smtpd_sasl_path                     = /var/spool/postfix/private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options         = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options     = $smtpd_sasl_security_options
smtpd_sasl_type                     = dovecot
smtpd_sender_login_maps             = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/virtual_domains_maps.cf
smtpd_sender_restrictions           = permit_mynetworks, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain, permit
smtpd_tls_auth_only                 = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file                 = /etc/ssl/private/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file                  = /etc/ssl/private/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel                  = 2
smtpd_tls_received_header           = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level            = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database    = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout     = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls                       = yes
tls_random_source                   = dev:/dev/urandom
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps                  = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/virtual_alias_maps.cf
virtual_gid_maps                    = static:2000
virtual_mailbox_base                = /var/www/mail/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains             = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps                = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_minimum_uid                 = 2000
virtual_transport                   = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
virtual_uid_maps                    = static:2000
```

`maillog` (after clicking "Get Messages" in Thunderbird

```
Jul 19 21:41:50 hwsrv-579344 dovecot[359560]: pop3-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x10, ret=1: before SSL initialization
Jul 19 21:41:50 hwsrv-579344 dovecot[359560]: pop3-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: before SSL initialization
Jul 19 21:41:50 hwsrv-579344 dovecot[359560]: pop3-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: before SSL initialization
Jul 19 21:41:50 hwsrv-579344 dovecot[359560]: auth: Debug: auth client connected (pid=359812)
Jul 19 21:41:50 hwsrv-579344 dovecot[359560]: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x10, ret=1: before SSL initialization
Jul 19 21:41:50 hwsrv-579344 dovecot[359560]: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: before SSL initialization
Jul 19 21:41:50 hwsrv-579344 dovecot[359560]: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: before SSL initialization
Jul 19 21:41:50 hwsrv-579344 dovecot[359560]: auth: Debug: auth client connected (pid=359813)
Jul 19 21:42:25 hwsrv-579344 dovecot[359560]: pop3-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: before SSL initialization
Jul 19 21:42:25 hwsrv-579344 dovecot[359560]: pop3-login: Debug: SSL error: Connection closed
Jul 19 21:42:25 hwsrv-579344 dovecot[359560]: pop3-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 35 secs): user=<>, rip=173.73.24.88, lip=142.11.253.50, TLS handshaking: Connection closed, session=<dBsQRNKqWS2tSRhY>
Jul 19 21:42:25 hwsrv-579344 dovecot[359560]: pop3-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: before SSL initialization
Jul 19 21:42:25 hwsrv-579344 dovecot[359560]: pop3-login: Debug: SSL error: Connection closed
Jul 19 21:42:25 hwsrv-579344 dovecot[359560]: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: before SSL initialization
Jul 19 21:42:25 hwsrv-579344 dovecot[359560]: imap-login: Debug: SSL error: Connection closed
Jul 19 21:42:25 hwsrv-579344 dovecot[359560]: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 35 secs): user=<>, rip=173.73.24.88, lip=142.11.253.50, TLS handshaking: Connection closed, session=<jkUWRNKqXC2tSRhY>
Jul 19 21:42:25 hwsrv-579344 dovecot[359560]: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: before SSL initialization
Jul 19 21:42:25 hwsrv-579344 dovecot[359560]: imap-login: Debug: SSL error: Connection closed
Jul 19 21:42:28 hwsrv-579344 dovecot[359560]: pop3-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x10, ret=1: before SSL initialization
Jul 19 21:42:28 hwsrv-579344 dovecot[359560]: pop3-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: before SSL initialization
Jul 19 21:42:28 hwsrv-579344 dovecot[359560]: pop3-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: before SSL initialization
Jul 19 21:42:28 hwsrv-579344 dovecot[359560]: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x10, ret=1: before SSL initialization
Jul 19 21:42:28 hwsrv-579344 dovecot[359560]: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: before SSL initialization
Jul 19 21:42:28 hwsrv-579344 dovecot[359560]: imap-login: Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: before SSL initialization
Jul 19 21:42:28 hwsrv-579344 dovecot[359560]: auth: Debug: auth client connected (pid=359824)
Jul 19 21:42:28 hwsrv-579344 dovecot[359560]: auth: Debug: auth client connected (pid=359825)
```

`maillog` (after trying to send mail through Roundcube from *foo@domain.com* to *bar@domain.com*)

```
Jul 19 22:20:54 hwsrv-579344 postfix/submission/smtpd[360356]: disconnect from 12345.localhostname.com[111.222.222.222] ehlo=2 starttls=1 auth=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=0/1 rset=1 quit=1 commands=8/9
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 postfix/submission/smtpd[360356]: connect from 12345.localhostname.com[111.222.222.222]
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 postfix/submission/smtpd[360356]: warning: connect to Milter service unix:/var/run/spamass-milter/spamass-milter.socket: Permission denied
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 postfix/submission/smtpd[360356]: setting up TLS connection from 12345.localhostname.com[111.222.222.222]
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 postfix/submission/smtpd[360356]: 12345.localhostname.com[111.222.222.222]: TLS cipher list "aNULL:-aNULL:HIGH:MEDIUM:+RC4:@STRENGTH"
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 postfix/submission/smtpd[360356]: SSL_accept:before SSL initialization
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 postfix/submission/smtpd[360356]: SSL_accept:before SSL initialization
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 postfix/submission/smtpd[360356]: SSL_accept:SSLv3/TLS read client hello
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 postfix/submission/smtpd[360356]: SSL_accept:SSLv3/TLS write server hello
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 postfix/submission/smtpd[360356]: SSL_accept:SSLv3/TLS write change cipher spec
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 postfix/submission/smtpd[360356]: SSL_accept:TLSv1.3 write encrypted extensions
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 postfix/submission/smtpd[360356]: SSL_accept:SSLv3/TLS write certificate
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 postfix/submission/smtpd[360356]: SSL_accept:TLSv1.3 write server certificate verify
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 postfix/submission/smtpd[360356]: SSL_accept:SSLv3/TLS write finished
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 postfix/submission/smtpd[360356]: SSL_accept:TLSv1.3 early data
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 postfix/submission/smtpd[360356]: SSL_accept:TLSv1.3 early data
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 postfix/submission/smtpd[360356]: SSL_accept:SSLv3/TLS read finished
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 postfix/submission/smtpd[360356]: 12345.localhostname.com[111.222.222.222]: Issuing session ticket, key expiration: 1595199052
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 postfix/submission/smtpd[360356]: 12345.localhostname.com[111.222.222.222]: save session E3966DA0AAC8A87053F861169C752EF9248773F52ED7C23B345072D992E4D4A8&s=submission&l=269488191 to smtpd cache
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 postfix/tlsmgr[360358]: put smtpd session id=E3966DA0AAC8A87053F861169C752EF9248773F52ED7C23B345072D992E4D4A8&s=submission&l=269488191 [data 136 bytes]
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 postfix/tlsmgr[360358]: write smtpd TLS cache entry E3966DA0AAC8A87053F861169C752EF9248773F52ED7C23B345072D992E4D4A8&s=submission&l=269488191: time=1595197296 [data 136 bytes]
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 postfix/submission/smtpd[360356]: SSL_accept:SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 postfix/submission/smtpd[360356]: 12345.localhostname.com[111.222.222.222]: Issuing session ticket, key expiration: 1595199052
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 postfix/submission/smtpd[360356]: 12345.localhostname.com[111.222.222.222]: save session 21BE69B853D66629D76AF0565BAF12FD3D4EF1BBAC38F329D3EC61D53AF95953&s=submission&l=269488191 to smtpd cache
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 postfix/tlsmgr[360358]: put smtpd session id=21BE69B853D66629D76AF0565BAF12FD3D4EF1BBAC38F329D3EC61D53AF95953&s=submission&l=269488191 [data 137 bytes]
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 postfix/tlsmgr[360358]: write smtpd TLS cache entry 21BE69B853D66629D76AF0565BAF12FD3D4EF1BBAC38F329D3EC61D53AF95953&s=submission&l=269488191: time=1595197296 [data 137 bytes]
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 postfix/submission/smtpd[360356]: SSL_accept:SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 postfix/submission/smtpd[360356]: Anonymous TLS connection established from 12345.localhostname.com[111.222.222.222]: TLSv1.3 with cipher TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (256/256 bits)
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 dovecot[359560]: auth: Debug: client in: AUTH#0112#011LOGIN#011service=smtp#011nologin#011lip=111.222.222.222#011rip=111.222.222.222#011secured
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 dovecot[359560]: auth: Debug: client passdb out: CONT#0112#011VXNlcm5hbWU6
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 dovecot[359560]: auth: Debug: client in: CONT<hidden>
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 dovecot[359560]: auth: Debug: client passdb out: CONT#0112#011UGFzc3dvcmQ6
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 dovecot[359560]: auth: Debug: client in: CONT<hidden>
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 dovecot[359560]: auth: Debug: sql(foo@domain.com,111.222.222.222): Performing passdb lookup
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 dovecot[359560]: auth-worker(360335): Debug: conn unix:auth-worker (pid=359563,uid=0): auth-worker<8>: Handling PASSV request
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 dovecot[359560]: auth-worker(360335): Debug: sql(foo@domain.com,111.222.222.222): Performing passdb lookup
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 dovecot[359560]: auth-worker(360335): Debug: sql(foo@domain.com,111.222.222.222): query: SELECT username as user, password, '/var/www/mail/vmail/domain.com/foo' as userdb_home, 'maildir:/var/www/mail/vmail/domain.com/foo' as userdb_mail, 2000 as userdb_uid, 2000 as userdb_gid FROM mailbox WHERE username = 'foo@domain.com' AND active = '1'
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 dovecot[359560]: auth-worker(360335): Debug: sql(foo@domain.com,111.222.222.222): Finished passdb lookup
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 dovecot[359560]: auth-worker(360335): Debug: conn unix:auth-worker (pid=359563,uid=0): auth-worker<8>: Finished
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 dovecot[359560]: auth: Debug: sql(foo@domain.com,111.222.222.222): Finished passdb lookup
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 dovecot[359560]: auth: Debug: auth(foo@domain.com,111.222.222.222): Auth request finished
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 dovecot[359560]: auth: Debug: client passdb out: OK#0112#011user=foo@domain.com
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 postfix/submission/smtpd[360356]: 3A3D790001A4: client=12345.localhostname.com[111.222.222.222], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=foo@domain.com
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 postfix/cleanup[360363]: 3A3D790001A4: message-id=<d464501c9c553acad309b6f6eb935fda@domain.com>
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 opendkim[80314]: default._domainkey.domain.com: key data is not secure: /etc/opendkim/keys/domain.com/default is in group 0 which has multiple users (e.g. "sync")
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 opendkim[80314]: 3A3D790001A4: error loading key 'default._domainkey.domain.com'
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 postfix/cleanup[360363]: 3A3D790001A4: milter-reject: END-OF-MESSAGE from 12345.localhostname.com[111.222.222.222]: 4.7.1 Service unavailable - try again later; from=<FH@domain.com> to=<bar@domain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<webmail.domain.com>
```

Thanks in advance for you help.  I've been racking my brain trying to figure out the problem.

EDIT:
Added Thunderbird log

```
2020-07-20 20:29:25.582000 UTC - [(null) 3344: Unnamed thread 1A1DF190]: D/IMAP ImapThreadMainLoop entering [this=1A155000]
2020-07-20 20:29:25.670000 UTC - [(null) 3344: Main Thread]: I/IMAP 1A155000:imap.domain.com:NA:SetupWithUrlCallback: clearing IMAP_CONNECTION_IS_OPEN
2020-07-20 20:29:25.670000 UTC - [(null) 3344: Unnamed thread 1A1DF190]: I/IMAP 1A155000:imap.domain.com:NA:ProcessCurrentURL: entering
2020-07-20 20:29:25.670000 UTC - [(null) 3344: Unnamed thread 1A1DF190]: I/IMAP 1A155000:imap.domain.com:NA:ProcessCurrentURL:imap://bar%40domain%2Ecom@imap.domain.com:993/select%3E/INBOX:  = currentUrl
2020-07-20 20:31:05.721000 UTC - [(null) 3344: Unnamed thread 1A1DF190]: D/IMAP ReadNextLine [stream=1A1E0060 nb=0 needmore=1]
2020-07-20 20:31:05.739000 UTC - [(null) 3344: Unnamed thread 1A1DF190]: I/IMAP 1A155000:imap.domain.com:NA:CreateNewLineFromSocket: clearing IMAP_CONNECTION_IS_OPEN - rv = 804b000e
2020-07-20 20:31:05.742000 UTC - [(null) 3344: Unnamed thread 1A1DF190]: I/IMAP 1A155000:imap.domain.com:NA:TellThreadToDie: close socket connection
2020-07-20 20:31:05.742000 UTC - [(null) 3344: Unnamed thread 1A1DF190]: I/IMAP 1A155000:imap.domain.com:NA:CreateNewLineFromSocket: (null)
2020-07-20 20:31:05.768000 UTC - [(null) 3344: Unnamed thread 1A1DF190]: I/IMAP 1A155000:imap.domain.com:NA:ProcessCurrentURL: aborting queued urls
2020-07-20 20:31:05.768000 UTC - [(null) 3344: Unnamed thread 1A1DF190]: D/IMAP ImapThreadMainLoop leaving [this=1A155000]
2020-07-20 20:36:24.186000 UTC - [(null) 3344: Unnamed thread 17C36190]: D/IMAP ImapThreadMainLoop entering [this=05026800]
2020-07-20 20:36:24.192000 UTC - [(null) 3344: Main Thread]: I/IMAP 05026800:imap.domain.com:NA:SetupWithUrlCallback: clearing IMAP_CONNECTION_IS_OPEN
2020-07-20 20:36:24.193000 UTC - [(null) 3344: Unnamed thread 17C36190]: I/IMAP 05026800:imap.domain.com:NA:ProcessCurrentURL: entering
2020-07-20 20:36:24.193000 UTC - [(null) 3344: Unnamed thread 17C36190]: I/IMAP 05026800:imap.domain.com:NA:ProcessCurrentURL:imap://bar%40domain%2Ecom@imap.domain.com:993/select%3E/INBOX:  = currentUrl
2020-07-20 20:38:04.230000 UTC - [(null) 3344: Unnamed thread 17C36190]: D/IMAP ReadNextLine [stream=1A1EADD0 nb=0 needmore=1]
2020-07-20 20:38:04.236000 UTC - [(null) 3344: Unnamed thread 17C36190]: I/IMAP 05026800:imap.domain.com:NA:CreateNewLineFromSocket: clearing IMAP_CONNECTION_IS_OPEN - rv = 804b000e
2020-07-20 20:38:04.236000 UTC - [(null) 3344: Unnamed thread 17C36190]: I/IMAP 05026800:imap.domain.com:NA:TellThreadToDie: close socket connection
2020-07-20 20:38:04.236000 UTC - [(null) 3344: Unnamed thread 17C36190]: I/IMAP 05026800:imap.domain.com:NA:CreateNewLineFromSocket: (null)
2020-07-20 20:38:04.252000 UTC - [(null) 3344: Unnamed thread 17C36190]: I/IMAP 05026800:imap.domain.com:NA:ProcessCurrentURL: aborting queued urls
2020-07-20 20:38:04.261000 UTC - [(null) 3344: Unnamed thread 17C36190]: D/IMAP ImapThreadMainLoop leaving [this=05026800]
```

Comment: Misconfigured SpamAssassin and Thunderbird, most likely.

Comment: @SKNB, try setting up logging on TB (https://wiki.mozilla.org/MailNews:Logging) and post any redacted results.

Comment: Edited OP to include the Thunderbird log

Answer (score 0):

It is not a client issue. The problem is here:

```
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 opendkim[80314]: default._domainkey.domain.com: key data is not secure: /etc/opendkim/keys/domain.com/default is in group 0 which has multiple users (e.g. "sync")
Jul 19 22:21:36 hwsrv-579344 opendkim[80314]: 3A3D790001A4: error loading key 'default._domainkey.domain.com'
```

Your server is using OpenDKIM and by default it's very particular about the permissions of its keys.

The technical reason for this is because they system's `sync` user is in group 0, `root`, and basically OpenDKIM is jealous that someone else is in group 0.

I don't know if it's safe to remove the `sync` user from group 0. I'm going to say that it's probably a really bad idea, so don't do that.

You can be *reasonably* safe if you modify `/etc/opendkim/opendkim.conf` and add the following line:

```
RequireSafeKeys         False
```

It's not perfect, because I assume OpenDKIM is being very cautious for a reason, or perhaps its default use case is for systems that don't have multiple users in group 0.

PS. In `/etc/postfix/main.cf` you can make the following change:

```
smtpd_tls_key_file                  = $smtpd_tls_cert_file
```

You can do this and remove `/etc/ssl/private/privkey.pem` altogether (as in, renaming it, not deleting it, in case something else breaks) because postfix supports having the key and cert in the same file. Your dovecot config is already doing this.